# 5Ghz Hotspot in Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi-hotspot

I run Fedora 31 on a Xidu Tour Pro laptop and most things work flawlessly out of the box. But so far I have not been able to create WiFi hotspots using the 5Ghz frequencies.

The Fedora Connection Manager basically says that "Activation of connection failed"
I ran journalctl for some additional details and found the following:

```
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6283] device (wlp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'Hotspot'

Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6392] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6395] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6404] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> disconnected
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6413] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disabled -> disconnected
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6507] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: >
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.6537] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING


Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7623] device (wlp1s0): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to EE:E6:96:D5:CF:74 (random)
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7691] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7698] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7727] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manag>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7738] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Hotspot' has security, but secrets are>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7741] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'man>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7882] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> disconnected
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7892] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disabled -> disconnected
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7896] device (wlp1s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'ma>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.7998] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manag>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8012] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Hotspot' has security, and secrets exist>
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8017] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Xidu'
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8020] Config: added 'mode' value '2'
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8022] Config: added 'frequency' value '5180'
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8025] Config: added 'freq_list' value '5035 5040 5045 5055 5060 5080 5170 5180 5190 5200 5210 >
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8026] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu NetworkManager[1020]: <info>  [1582575382.8028] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu wpa_supplicant[1091]: Note: nl80211 driver interface is not designed to be used with ap_scan=2; this can result in connection failures
Feb 24 21:16:22 xidu wpa_supplicant[1091]: wlp1s0: Failed to start AP functionality
```

Any advice how to further debug is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the computer as a Wi-Fi client with a 5 GHz network under Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

> Note: ap_scan=0/2 should not be used with the nl80211 driver interface (the
> current Linux interface). ap_scan=1 is the only option working with nl80211.